# Processing cannot find any device

Tags: java, android, processing, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3

I am having a lot of trouble getting started with Processing's android mode. It took me quite a while to enable the android mode and to get the sdk with all the right files in it, but just then another problem came up: it just cannot detect any device!

I have enabled the USB debugging on two android phones and tried it with both of them, but it didn't detect any of them. I have restarted the phones, disabled and enabled the USB debugging mode, but I always get the same result. I have run 'adb devices' on the command prompt, but the list of connected devices is always empty. Please give me suggestions as to how I should proceed from here.

My OS is Windows 8.1, and the two phones are Redmi Note 7 pro and Realme 5s, which both have Android 9.

Comment: In my experience cheaper phones lacked out of of the box Windows ADB drivers and I had to manually find/download/install these drivers. I'm guessing when you open device manager (e.g. run `devmgmt.msc`) you won't see the adb device there. Unfortunately the official website doesn't seem to advertise these drivers. I'd thread carefully and virus scan any potential adb driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment above: you need to make sure the Windows ADB drivers are installed for the device. From my experience, lower end smartphones tend not to have great developer support.

**Disclaimer** I do not own any of the devices you mention to test and won't be responsible for any potential damage trying the advice bellow.

Here are a few relevant bits of information

[XDA-developers forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/xiaomi-redmi-4x-to-adb-drivers-t3655367)
Relevant info:

> Go to Settings -> Permissions -> Install via USB: Uncheck your App if
> it's listed. Go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Privacy: Check
> the Unknown Sources option. Go to Settings -> Additional Settings ->
> Developer options: Check the Install via USB option. Go to Settings ->
> Additional Settings -> Developer options:Enable view attribute
> inspection Finally Go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer
> options:Turn off MIUI optimization. And then restart your device and
> whoooaaaa it will work i guaranteee..
>
> NOTE - Signin in to MI account is required to enable Install via USB
> option.
>
> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> Install "Google USB Driver"
>
> Go to Windows Device Manager, find "ADB Interface" -> update driver ->
> select manually -> select from list -> all devices -> select folder
> "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extra
> s\google\usb_driver" -> select "Android ADB Interface"
>
> Windows will warn you that this driver might not work, install it
> anyway
>
> Device manager will show "Android ADB Interface" ...

There's also this page:
https://c.mi.com/thread-1906671-1-0.html

However I'm not 100% sure it's legit: I'm weary of mediafire links.
Bare in mind this may be a risky download: always scan with using an antivirus with the latest definitions.

**Update:**
[Xiamo support Windows ADB Driver.](https://www.xiaomidrivers.net/xiaomi-adb-drivers-for-windows/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem was indeed with the ADB Interface, as no driver was installed. So I followed the instructions given in this video: https://youtu.be/PUjQnwULGzs and I managed to install the necessary drivers. I then had to update the driver software of my Redmi Note 7 pro, and for that I installed the Google USB Drivers from here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb . After this my phone started showing up in the command prompt when I would type 'adb devices'.